# Upload variable data (string) as a file to public AWS bucket

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a form which contains a file input field as shown below:

```
<form id="upload" action="http://touchtracker.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="Hansol/${filename}"><br>
    <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="file"> <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to  Amazon S3">
</form>
```

This form is submitting the files to a public AWS bucket. Further I have a variable called `bugout`, which contains some lengthy logs. I want to be able to upload a file to my AWS account using this form and the file should contain the data contained in this variable `bugout`.

I tried using the formData as follows, but it lead to 400 error

```
var fd = new FormData();
var file = new Blob([bugout.output], {type: 'plain/text'});
fd.append('file', file, 'fileName.txt');
fd.append('key','subFolder/${filename}');
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://touchtracker.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/',
    method: 'post',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,        //this...
    contentType: false         //and this is for formData type
});
```

Instead of `bugout.output`, I have tried sending just "abcd", so probably there is no problem with the payload. There are tonnes of error codes having 400 status on [AWS site](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html). How do I figure out from here?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just an issue with the order of two appends to the Formdata. Changing to the following order fixed the issue.

```
fd.append('key','subFolder/${filename}');
fd.append('file', file, 'fileName.txt');
```